# File transfer with multiple users

Tags: nexus-7, file-system, file-transfer, file-management, multi-user

On a rooted Nexus 7 (2013), I have set up a second user.

When I plug the usb cable to my mac, I can see all the files for the main user (using the Android File Transfer app from Google).

However, when I switch to the second user I can only see two folders:

.estrongs  and backups/apps

How can I access the rest of the files for that second user ?